# Can't execute text insert into div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a PHP page with a DIV block:

```
<div id="my_notice" class="my_notice ui-corner-all"></div>
```

This page, my-main.php, which is a class template form is loaded from another initial PHP after loading js file , as like as:

```
wp_register_script('my_notice_js', ......'notification/my-notice.js');
wp_enqueue_script('my_notice_js');

include_once( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'my-main.php');
new my_main_form;
```

and in this php when I need to execute verify operation I do:

```
function do_operation() {
 
 if ( $this->state === FALSE ) {
  if ( !isset($this->error_message) )
   $this->error_message = utf8_encode("Operation not completed!");
  ?><script type="text/javascript">showMyNotice('<?php echo $this->error_message; ?>', true);</script><?php
 } 
  .
  .
  .  
 }
```

where inside that .js file I have:

```
function showMyNotice(msg, alert) {
 console.log('executing showMyNotice....');
 $(window).scrollTop(0);
 $('#my_notice').text(msg).show("blind").delay(5000).toggle( "blind" );   
};
```

When I click on submit's form button showMyNotice is executed as in fact I see in Console that string "executing showMyNotice" and also the window goes on top as expetected , BUT seems the show-delay-toggle can't be executed...indeed if I execute that show-delay-toggle's instruction directly from Console then that works and I can see that div appearing....
I even settled that notification div as visible then calling from .js just to append message inside div but it didn't and directly from Console it does...

I even tried keep visible that DIV and just append the text with:

```
$('#my_notice').empty().append('showing some text...');
```

but it didn't appended...

Any direction would be appreciated... thanks in advance to all!!! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Uh, in your code, you show element with `show("blind")` first, and then you call `toggle("blind")` right away, which will hide the element. Maybe this happen too fast for you to see the element being shown.

To fix this, you can try to use `fadeOut()` function instead of `toggle()` to hide the element after a delay. Here is the modified `showMyNotice()` function:

```
function showMyNotice(msg, alert) {
 console.log('executing showMyNotice....');
 $(window).scrollTop(0);
 $('#my_notice').text(msg).show("blind").delay(5000).fadeOut( "slow" );   
};
```

Comment: HI @Brunno , thanks for your answer but in different pages I used that and it worked perfectly...I did right now a test: keeping visible the `DIV` and putting directly in `<script> ` block in main php template just a `console.log('<?php echo $this->error_message; ?>'); $("#my_notice").text('<?php echo $this->error_message; ?>');` but it doesn't even add into the div....indeed in the Console I get the echo correctly...